# How does system choose between application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: or a storyboard to set up window?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I'm comparing the templates for a Single View Application and an Empty Application in Xcode 4.6.3.  The Single View Application uses a Storyboard, and has a storyboard file that indicates which view to put in the window when the app starts.  The Empty Application sets up and assigns the view to the window in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

So why is the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method empty in the delegate for the templates that use a storyboard?  In this same method, I would expect to see the code telling it to refer to the storyboard to build and assign the initial window and view, since it is the same method used in the other template.  These delegates otherwise look the same.

I'm asking because I want to know how I can switch to using a storyboard later if I need to and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using storyboards, it will automatically instantiate the view controller that is assigned as the "root" controller. This is evident by an arrow on the left side of a controller screen pointing to that screen. As to your question about what determines whether the setup occurs, there is a key in your `APP-Info.plist` file that will tell iOS to look for a storyboard.

> Main storyboard file base name - "MainStoryboard"

So, therefore, to add storyboards to your project without the template, you need to create a `.storyboard` file and then set this key-value pair in your app's plist file.

I hope this clears things up a bit.